# AsyncTask get a wrong String parameter

Tags: java, android, string, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm trying to load bitmaps in the asyncTask, in the onClick I will execute myAsyncTask and get bitmap as result. I'm stuck with NullPointerException, because String parameter, that I put to myAsyncTack is decoded wrong (see logcat screenshot, first line is log.d of String data[position], and the second is from myAsyncTask decode method). In my code I need to open lots of images at background, how can I do it right with myAsyncTask?

execute:

```
        Log.d("Files", "DATA: " + data[position]);
        try{
            ImageView mImg = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            BitmapTask btmt = new BitmapTask();
            btmt.execute(data[position]);
            mImg.setImageBitmap(btmt.get());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return vi;
```

async:

```
public class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... bmt) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + bmt);
            int targetWidth  = bm.getWidth() / 1;
            int targetHeight = bm.getHeight() / 1;

            Bitmap size = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, matrix(), true);
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        }

    }
```

logcat:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + bmt);
```

to this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + bmt[0]);
```

You have to get first element of `String... bmt` string array.

Comment: thanks, that solve an issue but my images loading time is still very slow, is ther any other problems in my code?

Comment: No, but I will recommend to try [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) library for loading image fast.And, glad to help. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `onPostExecute` method to set the bitmap to the `ImageView`.

It will be executed on the `UI` thread when the task is completed.

Try something like this:

```
public class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask {

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... bmt) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + bmt);
        int targetWidth  = bm.getWidth() / 1;
        int targetHeight = bm.getHeight() / 1;

        Bitmap size = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, matrix(), true);
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        this.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView){
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }


}
```

and

```
Log.d("Files", "DATA: " + data[position]);
    try{
        ImageView mImg = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        BitmapTask btmt = new BitmapTask();
        btmt.setImageView(mImg);
        btmt.execute(data[position]);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return vi;
```

Answer (score 0):

The file located at Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + bmt does not exist, and throws a FileNotFoundexcption in BitmapTask. Surround with try catch to avoid crash :)

Comment: at the logcat you can see the file is ok

Answer (score 0):

Use

`public class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Check params> {
}`

Check the [params]

Use `<String, Integer, Void>` as you need

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

```
Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

Also add

```
String fileName = bmt[0];
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MANUAL/workflow/" + fileName;
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Check the add at bottom. You are not getting the params