# Loading Thumbnails into a Bitmap Array - best practice

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Being a complete novice to Android and (admittedly) not the strongest programmer - I want to ask for some advice on loading thumbnail images into a Bitmap Array, which is loaded into a custom adapter.

The thumbnails are very small (around 5KB).

I add the thumbnails to a Bitmap array in an Async task.  I am using drawables which are dummy images.  So I load the entire list with dummy images (I load the actual images later on).

I am worried if the user browses a folder with 200+ images.  I could possibly get an out of memory error.  I want a way to prevent this, perhaps only load what is needed in the visible display, and load more if needed?

I have read a lot of other questions and advice on recycling Bitmaps, but I'm still not sure where tog o from here.

```
   @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {
        //Opens thumbnails for each image contained in the  folder
        try {
        DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];

        Bitmap image=null;

        int loopCount=0; //I use this to identify where in the adapter the real image should go
        for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {

            try{

                if(!fileInfo.isFolder)
                {
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    pix.add(image);
                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                    loopCount++;

                }
                else
                {
                    //must be a folder if it has no thumb, so add folder icon
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dbfolder);
                    pix.add(image);
                    paths.add(fileInfo.path);
                    loopCount++;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.gc();

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the getView from the Custom Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View v = arg1;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (arg1 == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filename);
         holder.iconImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

        holder.title.setText(folderName.get(position).toString());


    holder.iconImage.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is that when using an adapter, the views are created only when they are displayed on the screen. It means that you don't need and you must not decode all the bitmaps.

The best practice is to decode each bitmap in an `AsyncTask` when the associated view is created. The bitmap will be decoded in the `doInBackground` method and set to the `ImageView` in the `onPostExecute` method (as it's executed on the `UI thread`).

Then you might also want to use RAM or disk cache to reload previously decoded bitmaps more efficiently.

Please take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html for more information about how to display bitmaps efficiently.

Comment: I am using an Async task- the code above is in the doInBackground.  In the postExecute I bind the Adapter and everything is added to the ListView.  I'll change my code to add my complete async task

Comment: Yes but you should create an AsyncTask for a single bitmap which will be started in the getView method so you don't have to decode all bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added my adapter code so you can see how I set the image.  How can I tell the adapter whether to load a drawable or not?

Comment: Your AsyncTask should decode only one bitmap. Take a look at this comment, it might inspire you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106657/asynctask-get-a-wrong-string-parameter/23107423#23107423

Comment: The Asynctask is started in the getView method and decode the bitmap needed for the view.